# How do I create and save a Scheme program with .scm file extension using DrRacket?

Tags: scheme, racket

All I am able to make in DrRacket is racket document files, but I need those files to have a Scheme file extension or more specifically .scm

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Note a .scm extension implies that it is a Scheme program, likely usable by multiple Scheme compilers.  If you are using DrRacket specific functions/syntax it might be appropriate to avoid .scm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the "Save Definitions As..." item under the "File" menu and write the file name as `<something>.scm`. SCM was the file extension used in DrScheme, DrRacket's previous incarnation, but you can still use it for saving your programs.

Comment: Actually, I think `.ss` was a more common extension back in the PLT Scheme days.